# How do I execute functions in subject synchronously?

Tags: c#, reactive-programming, system.reactive

The problem I want to solve is, that I want to kick of an asynchronous action from multiple threads but only one action execution at a time is permitted.

The action is to communicate with a hardware device and the device can only handle one request at a time.

One of my ideas was to synchronize this with a `System.Reactive.Subjects.Subject`. Multiple threads could call `OnNext` and the subject should have executed one request after the other. I wrote this (probably very naive) code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var source = new System.Reactive.Subjects.Subject<Func<Task<int>>>();

    source
        // from http://code.fitness/post/2016/11/rx-selectmany-deep-dive.html
        .SelectMany(async x => await x.Invoke()) 
        .Subscribe(result => Console.WriteLine($"Work of index {result} completed"));

    var noOfThreads = 3;
    for (var i = 0; i < noOfThreads; i++)
    {
        var i1 = i;
        var t = new Thread(() => source.OnNext(() => doWork(i1)));
        t.Start();
    }

    Console.ReadKey();
}

static async Task<int> doWork(int index)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Start work {index}");
    await Task.Delay(1000);
    Console.WriteLine($"Stop work {index}");
    return index;
}
```

My hope was an output like this:

```
Start work 2
Stop work 2
Work of index 2 completed
Start work 0
Stop work 0
Work of index 0 completed
```

Instead I get:

```
Start work 0
Start work 1
Start work 2
Stop work 1
Stop work 0
Work of index 1 completed
Work of index 0 completed
Stop work 2
Work of index 2 completed
```

This shows that all actions are started right from the start and there is no waiting for the other ones to complete. I wonder if `Reactive` is the right way to do that, or if there is some else clever way I can accomplish my task.

**Edit**: to give more background information why I need this: The application communicates with a device. This device has a serial interface and can only handle one command at a time. So I have a thread that constantly gets status updates like:

```
while (true)
{
    ReadPosition();
    ReadTempereatures();
    ReadErrors();
}
```

Then there is a ui, where users can initiate some action on the device. 
My current solution is a queue where I enqueue my commands. That works but I was wondering, if a event approach would be working as well.

Comment: Why would you write multi threaded code if you want it to happen sequentially?  You could of course add to your loop to wait until the thread has completed.

Comment: But why? I mean ... solution can be as simple as changing the thread count of the `Task` stuff ... but still, why you want to do this? Could you provide more details here please? As the correct solution depends fully on what the exact goal is

Comment: One thread is used to constantly pull data (state information) from the device and another thread is the ui where users may kick off some actions.

Comment: But why you need those exactly handled one by one?

Comment: Thanks for your question! Your interest is very welcomed. I wrote an edit to address it.

Comment: Well ... the short answer then is no, you need to process this serial or (as alternative) use mutexes. A queue is probably the best solution as it is the most robust one though (only one thread to worry about). You could however change this to something that allows for simpler creation (eg. a special object adding to the queue automatically and taking a func)

Comment: You're mixing Rx, Tasks, and threading. No wonder it's going off the rails. Pick on approach - Rx is the best, IMHO - and you should be fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're mixing Rx, Tasks, and threading. No wonder it's going off the rails. Pick one approach - Rx is the best, IMHO - and you should be fine.

Does this suffice:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var source = new Subject<Func<int>>();

    source
        .Synchronize()
        .Select(x => x())
        .Subscribe(result => Console.WriteLine($"Work of index {result} completed"));

    var noOfThreads = 3;
    for (var i = 0; i < noOfThreads; i++)
    {
        var i1 = i;
        var t = new Thread(() => source.OnNext(() => doWork(i1)));
        t.Start();
    }

    Console.ReadLine();
}

static int doWork(int index)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Start work {index}");
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
    Console.WriteLine($"Stop work {index}");
    return index;
}
```

That gives:

```
Start work 0
Stop work 0
Work of index 0 completed
Start work 2
Stop work 2
Work of index 2 completed
Start work 1
Stop work 1
Work of index 1 completed
```

The key is to call `.Synchronize()` to bring all of the calling threads under the Rx contract.

Comment: I know it is a big mixup :). The result is competently what I am looking for! Thanks for the tip with `Synchronize()`.
My code in `doWork` is an async request operation, but I guess in this case I don't not benefit so I could refactor to a synchronous version.

Comment: @ChristianMurschall Instead of refactoring, just put a Wait on it

Comment: Thanks for the great suggestion! I'm using now a `BlockingCollection` that fits my use case slightly better.